# Regular expression : remove words and number

Tags: java, regex

I have a string and I want to remove the string `Input! + word + digits` and `Calc! + word + digits` from it. I have also included my attempt.

```
Input : IF(Input!B34 + Calc!B45)
```

```
Output : Input!B34 Calc!B45
```

My attempt :

```
Pattern findMyPattern = Pattern.compile("Input!\\w\\d|" + worksheetName+ "!.+?");
        Matcher foundAMatch = findMyPattern.matcher(input);
        HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();
        while (foundAMatch.find()) {
            String s = foundAMatch.group(0);
            hashSet.add(s);
        }
```

What regular expression should I use ? I tried using a few of them. But I am not expert in them. Some idea will be useful.

Comment: Your example output has `Calc!45`, but the input had a `B` character - wasn't that supposed to be preserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
"(?:Input|Calc)![a-zA-Z]\\d+"
```

Explanation:

```
(?:Input|Calc)  // Match `Input or Calc`
 !              // Followed by !
[a-zA-Z]        // Followed by an alphabetical character
\\d+            // Then digits.
```

And use it with `Matcher#find` and then add `matcher.group()` to your `Set`.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Leave a comment please. Since I've tested this code on OP input, I would really like to hear something from you.